# Any way to get Mathematica to Solve[Sin[Tan[x]]-Tan[Sin[x]]==0,x]?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, trigonometry

```
Solve[Sin[Tan[x]] - Tan[Sin[x]] == 0, x]
```

It says it runs out of methods.  After a very long time.  Plotting the expression shows there are periodic solutions and some very nasty bits, too.  NSolve does no better.

Comment: Note that ``Reduce`` also returns an obviously *wrong* exact solution $x=884279719003555/140737488355328$.

Comment: You need higher precision. Try ``N[..., 5]``. Also, note that the value of this fraction is approximately $2\pi$.

Comment: @Domen - If you encapsulate the whole equation, i.e., `Table[N[Sin[Tan[884279719003555/140737488355328]] - Tan[Sin[884279719003555/140737488355328]] == 0, prec],{prec, 5, 50, 5}]` it evaluates to `True` for each precision.

Comment: @BobHanlon, I am really not an expert in numerical methods, but if you increase the maximal possible precision: ``Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 200}, Table[...]]``, you see that the result [is False](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Y1p.png).

Comment: To add to @Domen's (accurate) comments, the fraction is the double-precision representation of $2\pi$: evaluate `SetPrecision[N[2 Pi], Infinity]`.  It is slightly less than $2\pi$.

Comment: `Solve[{Sin[Tan[x]] - Tan[Sin[x]] == 0, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi }, x, Reals]`  finds all real solutions !

Comment: The incorrect rational approximation to 2 pi will be gone in the next release (I checked before submitting a bug report).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this:

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 200},
 Solve[Sin[Tan[x]] - Tan[Sin[x]] == 0, x, Reals]
 ]
```

[image]

If you want complex solutions, then you'll have to bound the domain probably — that is, more powerful methods exist on a bounded domain.

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 200},
 Solve[Sin[Tan[x]] - Tan[Sin[x]] == 0 && 
   0 <= Re@x < 2 Pi && -2 < Im[x] < 2, x]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way I found (using Maxima, not Mathematica)  but should be possible to do in Mathematica as well...  convert the expression to complex exponentials, and factor it.
One factor is exp(exp(I x)) + exp(exp(- I x)).
setting this to zero and solving gives   x=I log(-1)  or x=0.  I think this corresponds to a complete set, depending on how you feel about log(-1)  (= ln(-1)) being multi-valued.

Another approach is to use Maxima's  bf_find_root(f,x,a,b)    (bigfloat version), which requires input of a function and 2 values where the sign of f(a) and f(b) differ. Finding a root between 1 and 6, with precision 100 decimal digits gives the root
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117068b0

which agrees with the value of pi to all places.
Thanks for your suggestions on different approaches, and bug fix promise.
RJF

Comment: `FindRoot[Sin[Tan[x]] - Tan[Sin[x]] == 0, {x, 3}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]` gives the same result as `bf_find_root`.